# What is a "Detoation?"

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In the dungeon Pharos Sirius, some area blasts are called "*Aetherial Detoation*". What is a detoation? A typo/bug? Something from Final Fantasy lore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks to me like a bug (a localization typo). [This thread](http://forum.square-enix.com/ffxiv/threads/155982-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88-Beast-Tribe-Quest-Mount-Action-and-Aetherial-Detoation) on the official forums seems to confirm that:

The original poster [asks](http://forum.square-enix.com/ffxiv/threads/155982-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88-Beast-Tribe-Quest-Mount-Action-and-Aetherial-Detoation?p=1986679&viewfull=1#post1986679):

> The aether bomb in Pharos Sirius, the ones near "Aether Valve"s on the
>   stair cases causes "Aetherial Detoation". I'd be inclined to say that
>   it most probably should have been "Aetherial Detonation"

A user identified as a "Dev Team" member [replies](http://forum.square-enix.com/ffxiv/threads/155982-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88-Beast-Tribe-Quest-Mount-Action-and-Aetherial-Detoation?p=2005226&viewfull=1#post2005226):

> Good eye! These issues will be resolved with a future update. Thank
>   you!

Comment: I'm reminded of the *"dedotated wam"* comment.